# A word for someone who wrongly belittles others for using a larger vocabulary?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, adjectives, antonyms

EDIT:

Some people can wrongly accuse others of being pretentious, verbose, or wordy ***JUST*** for having larger vocabularies (even slightly).

Is there a definition for people like this?

Thanks kindly for any help.

Comment: Neither "verbose" nor "wordy" are about the size of someone's vocabulary. They "degrade" people who use many words to say (or try to say) what could be said in fewer words. It's entirely possible to be verbose and wordy with a very limited vocabulary. (I don't know what "lexiphanic" means, and my dictionary doesn't either.)

Comment: "Neither "verbose" nor "wordy" are about the size of someone's vocabulary." I know, that's what I also meant: people can wrongly resort to using such words when confronted by rare or unconventional words. Lexiphanic means somebody who uses bombastic or pretentious language. I'll try to re-edit my post for more clarity, my apologies.

Comment: Trying to understand.  Are you looking for a way to describe someone who is insecure about his word choice?

Comment: I mean people who incorrectly accuse others of being pretentious, verbose, or wordy JUST for having larger vocabularies. I know this seems like silly behaviour, but I have actually seen it online and was wondering if there was a definition for such people.

Comment: You want a word for people with small vocabularies who complain about people who use fancy words?

Comment: Well, I've even seen people accused of being pretentious for using words that aren't even considered "fancy", but something along those lines, yes. I was wondering if there happened to be a good word for this sort of behaviour.

Comment: "Snob", perhaps? Or maybe just "Jealous"? Lol. What I'd go with is "Judgmental", since they are making assumptions about someone based on the way they talk...

Comment: I know what you mean, but I was hoping for something more specific. In an ideal world, I'd create a new word/definition like "Vocabism: Discrimination against people with large or small vocabularies. A person who does this is a Vocabist". Ha.